# Change the normalfont to bold face in the caption of the List of Figures and Tables

Tags: tables, floats, bold

I want Change the normalfont to bold face in the caption of the List of Figures and Tables.

My code:

```
\newpage

\listoftables*

\newpage

\begin{center}
  \tableofcontents*
\end{center}
```

My list of figures and tables[image]: 
[image]

I want:
[image]

link of project : [enter link description here](https://www.overleaf.com/17901912xvhybssgydyx#/67839229/)

Comment: Welcome! Please post code for a minimal document which produces the output you show as what you have now. Note that questions should not depend on the content of external links, but should be self-sufficient so that they remain useful for others and are more likely to get answered, too.

Comment: I don't know the class and code you are using. I'm guessing the `memoir` class because of the `\listoftables*` command you use. If that is right then you are asking 3 questions in one go: Bold the headings. Center the headings, Bold the caption numbers and put something before them. I have an answer for the first of these (with the `memoir` class) but have no desire to try to answer the others without more information from you.

Comment: My main question is how to change the font normal of figure 1 of  lof, as example to bold face. The class of project is abtntex2.